# Algorithm fails to execute on final array values

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I'm attempting to solve a problem where I'm tasked with compressing a char array in-place by counting the occurrences of a character and adding that count next to the character. For example, given this input:

```
['a','a','b','b','c','c','c']
```

I need to return this:

```
['a','2','b','2','c','3']
```

Because `a` occurs twice, `b` occurs twice, and `c` occurs 3 times. It doesn't matter what is in the remaining array indices. If the count is more than one digit, the individual numbers must be placed sequentially. So if `a` occurs 12 times in a given array, the result should be `[ 'a', '1', '2' ]`.

I want to solve this using a two-pointer approach. One pointer would be a slow pointer, another would be a fast one. The slow one is used to get the character for comparison and moves only when a new character is found. To ensure the slow one finds the next character, I move it based on the number of digits in the `count` variable. The fast one continuously increases and is used to get a count of each character; this count resets if a different character is found. To deal with multiple digits in `count`, I manipulate the number by converting it to a `String`.

However, using the example given, my code gives the following result:

```
['a','2','b','2','c','c','c']
```

I've run it through a debugger and it seems that my code fails to check the final sequence(s) of the array properly. I'm not sure how to fix this- how can I change my code to loop through the array properly? Here is my code:

```
public static char[] compress(char[] chars) {
    if (chars.length == 1) return chars;
    int count = 1;
    int slow = 0;
    for (int fast = 1; fast < chars.length; fast++) {
        if (chars[slow] != chars[fast]) {
            int pos = 1;
            String countStr = String.valueOf(count);
            for (int j = 0; j < countStr.length(); j++) {
                chars[slow + pos] = countStr.charAt(j);
                pos++;
            }
            count = 1;
            slow += pos;
        } else {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return chars;
}
```

Run using:

```
compress(new char[] {'a','a','b','b','c','c','c'});
```

Comment: What is the expected output for `['a','a','b','a']`?

Comment: You can assume the input is always sorted

Comment: Thanks. What is the expected output for ['a','b']?

Comment: Should be `['a','1','b','1']`. Just realized that makes my error check wrong but I'll leave it there to avoid confusion.

Comment: Do you know that your inputs are in sorted order?

Comment: I feel it's worth noting that a map is the standard way of doing this. It would be a lot simpler and would also not require a sorted list.

Comment: "I want to solve this using a two-pointer approach." Just curious if this is part of the problem itself or just how you would like to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you never run the substitution for the final character, only when the character changes.
You'll need to do an additional character substitution at the end, after the for loop terminates.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach here (pseudocode) is:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < chars.length) {
  int start = i++;
  while (i < chars.length && chars[i] == chars[start]) {
    ++i;
  }

  int count = i - start;
  // Write chars[start] and count to the output.
}
```

Because this writes `chars[start]` and `count` on each iteration of the outer loop, it doesn't miss off the last iteration when you hit the end of the array: it's handled the same way as all other runs.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can add different character (different than last actual last ) at last of your array then it will work